# Graphviz dot generates a very large black image only for one document

Tags: image, graphviz, dot

So when I use graphviz dot to create a simple graph is works entirely as expected, this code:

```
digraph simple {
    "1313213"-> "123123"
    "123123" -> "adsagj"
}
```

Creates this image:

[image]

As expected but for some reason when I use the following code:

```
digraph json_data {
    graph [bgcolor=white]
    "4d990f29-cd09-44ab-8ff2-87f9a0bebe86" [label="10811"]
    "c4bffbf7-d258-4b5c-b87b-6a8bc861295d" [label="10810"]
    "8f86a5cc-8a0a-4380-91f5-2ab754ab9711" [label="10809"]
    "d77e4d0f-673c-4ac4-8411-ab7cc8ee840a" [label="10808"]
    "8e4d4f32-2689-4e3e-991b-95319d84ef8a" [label="10807"]
    "19998f18-4e0d-4060-8a3f-c66a6bb9ac22" [label="10806"]
    "e3ccf1ec-5aa6-4cd5-a66f-1c0b629093e5" [label="10805"]
    "8f7ac128-a046-43e7-ab51-c1214734a0c0" [label="10804"]
    "f7579872-4a5c-4594-937f-b264542d6637" [label="10803"]
    "38d04ed2-ea78-4c35-8265-76a58d71e3b5" [label="10802"]
    "e6ffca19-6b61-426e-8f8e-f8df40ccf4cd" [label="10801"]
    "bd120709-a05b-4e9c-a23e-67b656579327" [label="10800"]
    "820c6728-30c5-4d9f-bbe0-f772fa2d4b2e" [label="10799"]
    "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b" [label="10798"]
    "5c08b7d4-faa0-45d1-8dad-e9bd2c7ef051" [label="10797"]
    "b864bd1b-60ca-46a6-a1da-1ea189fef441" [label="10750"]
    "45c73173-a40e-4cbe-b673-a6ae80f2df9f" [label="10746"]
    "432c7e91-997a-46d8-a8f8-3298a7f7df58" [label="10740"]
    "4b450007-ad7a-4d7b-9df3-c082b80b00ca" [label="10739"]
    "13d9629e-f56f-4b47-bc99-376ecb14b076" [label="10729"]
    "c837a0a7-78d1-40ac-bf43-7868f0ff3957" [label="10728"]
    "a8cbc679-d6e8-4c6c-b715-cf8d7d23c555" [label="10663"]
    "40659aaf-fe64-42fc-ae94-9987ffb3b686" [label="10619"]
    "0de017a7-4ef4-495d-bee0-efaba0b4da02" [label="10618"]
    "4356074e-b446-474a-89e7-e93cc158d24e" [label="10617"]
    "6d517284-8254-4f10-ab98-2dea61c8d04f" [label="10568"]
    "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e" [label="10567"]
    "fa4565ee-59d5-4af2-b9bd-c1632d2a6c6c" [label="10564"]
    "f2b95876-df48-49e4-8f88-9e32674c33a0" [label="10400"]
    "2ce72a20-14b8-41f1-b21f-47a7681c6276" [label="10368"]
    "93a23f0d-c8b4-4a95-9f62-4502e42d87fc" [label="10335"]
    "a44919e5-8860-4e67-8c53-42e5d439c58e" [label="10300"]
    "2f4a908a-8269-4247-b374-729eac540269" [label="10299"]
    "db25cc7b-ab41-4389-a8dd-cb294b504fdd" [label="10221"]
    "7dd1a130-6c0f-475a-b432-562a0e338839" [label="10079"]
    "85d507d8-0c2f-413d-a0db-ceeaf5569adb" [label="9660"]
    "bbbc9a61-e2b2-4f6e-91cd-d46ae14b71fc" [label="9642"]
    "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809" [label="9641"]
    "1ac8fea0-791e-4d5b-9db5-095d1c1fee82" [label="9639"]
    "3846ee3e-36d1-495c-9adc-088c715c257d" [label="9635"]
    "c7b64c7b-c451-4d5b-905c-e465201905ef" [label="9601"]
    "c0b71383-6ab0-4786-90d7-4d50588df620" [label="9245"]
    "9bc5c5f2-e45f-4ae8-817e-2e2a84d63d6e" [label="9229"]
    "ec25527a-f1cb-4827-896f-229fb135af50" [label="9206"]
    "30e0cc04-69bf-4a98-b5b7-ad102851a539" [label="9035"]
    "fb573682-cf5f-4867-a40c-d151cb2dd5fd" [label="8942"]
    "20fc5d12-f614-49e8-9836-9890bb3f7a37" [label="8941"]
    "5f0c0a21-cc3c-47d3-a143-a540b8f2681a" [label="8940"]
    "a95a4daf-8b24-4e30-9a44-85b800e75bff" [label="8911"]
    "a20078e8-1df2-42a3-8f8c-bc5b821dd2a5" [label="8898"]
    "2c0c4fc1-3b3e-4a4e-aa7e-9f39c0302031" [label="8897"]
    "5224aa2b-5969-4433-97cb-0cfa0c5a5110" [label="8894"]
    "72233b5c-bf90-479f-9ede-8b8a6e921130" [label="8682"]
    "c9a96a2f-b6b7-4235-a131-b76489d6e230" [label="8600"]
    "2abf0a74-85ab-49eb-85bd-8429ec4d3bca" [label="8597"]
    "b5e4c5e3-bcc1-4620-9739-9a0a10915ac2" [label="8596"]
    "02b3d381-cf40-42ff-8a4e-67afaa049e2d" [label="8595"]
    "d58124c5-534d-4789-b6c3-8148f970b03f" [label="8594"]
    "25dfee0c-8686-4150-8f8e-ddb766f8fa11" [label="8593"]
    "5586a6e8-568c-466c-a3d0-88994b493b37" [label="8592"]
    "3e7781f4-5a64-4c49-be15-659669f51052" [label="8591"]
    "a1d06b37-6248-4756-80be-5cce023254a8" [label="8590"]
    "85b6d1ed-0458-46bc-8130-7f30a2fe6038" [label="8589"]
    "26f13b51-483f-4053-b2a0-a89e6c7dc181" [label="8588"]
    "22b6e967-70a7-4995-bee8-fa56babac7ac" [label="8587"]
    "76aa7f44-cdb8-4641-bcf0-627fdea8b8f8" [label="8586"]
    "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235" [label="8585"]
    "47e0d907-34d2-4257-ad81-9faf89fe3e59" [label="8542"]
    "5ba6cd5e-0138-49f3-a874-52b09263d57c" [label="8527"]
    "3dd16fdb-79c1-47e4-94e1-db4bf3e69e72" [label="8377"]
    "6cc95bb2-47d9-437d-b4d6-91e37eb765f4" [label="6373"]
    "3322a081-0b4f-4241-992a-044614ab260c" [label="6372"]
    "0f79d52a-3785-4f17-8732-3d958af0b98e" [label="6371"]
    "916d3373-19c5-4159-9115-7982c218dfb6" [label="6370"]
    "ee98f049-2a1f-468c-8f16-be9ca7d21d87" [label="6369"]
    "d85211ca-bd8e-4203-a046-644835033e54" [label="6367"]
    "e132a55c-f561-43a5-8584-47f3611bbf53" [label="6366"]
    "b3ea090c-c534-4efa-802b-758f61c48fdb" [label="6365"]
    "b9694ce4-04b0-4964-a65d-ead392830ad4" [label="6364"]
    "d4b29e8e-a781-41f5-9e71-11029e12b157" [label="6362"]
    "0e80a296-e282-415c-a136-adb4ab285259" [label="6360"]
    "50ff3b85-f711-4eba-af67-7e4dfb8467bd" [label="6353"]
    "77db6307-f2ef-4854-86af-c23a2459febc" [label="6352"]
    "0a0ca52d-d2ba-4da2-8a0c-47f43af8bdd1" [label="6351"]
    "e60af8ef-0416-46b1-8a28-16fdf8b10a35" [label="6350"]
    "b4c59220-b3c4-471d-8fca-38daaffbd8b7" [label="6349"]
    "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b" [label="6348"]
    "9291e7df-b044-4615-b816-1f964ce4f574" [label="6347"]
    "474ef404-ed96-4226-a080-6496a600fbdc" [label="6209"]
    "fe11be3f-fef2-4760-ad99-8e323f01748d" [label="6208"]
    "4cccf502-fe34-4c68-94fb-dfa25fc34b90" [label="6207"]
    "611d41f6-6540-4dec-95b6-fb21dc4e14a1" [label="6206"]
    "d21e0d43-7595-41dd-bdc9-3984b1e2e0ef" [label="6205"]
    "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77" [label="6204"]
    "0e8b0fcd-5fec-4aac-b65c-6e391bf7bfd1" [label="6203"]
    "dd0340d5-c0d5-40a6-a988-d7204ec6e783" [label="6202"]
    "940955cf-7bb8-497d-aea2-6e5d841b7fb1" [label="6200"]
    "f8bd4edb-8a09-4912-8edb-f14f368ef7c2" [label="6197"]
    "2322f347-7153-437a-843a-8f10a4e57e1b" [label="6193"]
    "10876c73-aef9-40ff-b5dd-259a4ce47292" [label="6191"]
    "ebb6349e-5432-4d0d-9101-e3d19d584a2c" [label="6190"]
    "216eaafa-5d84-4744-989e-7d9558314dca" [label="6189"]
    "9eeca7f7-ab14-4e38-8d64-8b9d54dff3f6" [label="6188"]
    "aecd60a1-436a-42c3-bdc8-227547e48ba5" [label="6187"]
    "77cad941-30ac-4b81-ad4a-4409f1da21ed" [label="6151"]
    "6e4639ef-8e6f-427f-a417-c344d736c27b" [label="6111"]
    "390ae27c-34de-49dd-b162-7bf898f3a44d" [label="6110"]
    "f93323bd-dc69-4f83-b920-0aad440339d5" [label="6108"]
    "864aa807-e56c-4aa2-93d6-1612710f2028" [label="6107"]
    "c8287fa1-e950-402e-aa8f-83995f3d44b6" [label="5587"]
    "825d4f6c-15dc-4be1-9318-a802d3f6bf12" [label="5475"]
    "eff5b030-606c-4dfa-8bb0-8fe92cd525df" [label="5474"]
    "f9d9e5b1-07da-44d4-934d-e88f53fc40f7" [label="5473"]
    "70e957b9-8f41-4b52-9480-ce3af6a3009b" [label="5472"]
    "09f4d03b-a1b3-4ed4-95c4-c62d9690982f" [label="5470"]
    "de83aa71-3a24-4d7a-8ca2-661a5d942c43" [label="5469"]
    "723ec621-ff8c-40ca-8efc-021dee4c4ef9" [label="5468"]
    "4a0ef549-0236-4a38-b32c-4769d25e5646" [label="5467"]
    "daf8022f-ae83-4336-98aa-0ace0a033243" [label="5464"]
    "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057" [label="5463"]
    "0a8b61ad-a068-4f75-8993-227149af0a57" [label="5439"]
    "c771b13f-cb34-42af-b8cd-44bcd600c777" [label="5292"]
    "adc7c5fc-e529-4141-a3f6-7a660f80a69f" [label="5080"]
    "cd9807ad-38bf-4738-9807-0854d5bdc3d9" [label="5069"]
    "fee9052b-7c71-4323-9fba-adeb2f32fdcf" [label="4991"]
    "bda49732-7b5e-45ee-a38b-d6a0cb39fdde" [label="4095"]
    "b2a5fab8-c92d-4b88-9283-b8432841aa87" [label="4049"]
    "9983c8a8-6ef4-47e6-ae00-9f43dcdf5eeb" [label="4041"]
    "24fac911-fae6-48c0-8498-78a7c97a83ad" [label="4034"]
    "81190b5c-ab3a-41e8-935c-ac035710f90e" [label="4033"]
    "2e28a740-7991-4cfe-8ed0-9d95c8181e29" [label="4027"]
    "c3f7aceb-9004-4d9f-a719-077d3e614590" [label="4026"]
    "8912e27a-6c17-46ca-b01b-219711dd1505" [label="4025"]
    "b7bd2585-368e-4aa6-a512-c6a358f86af1" [label="4019"]
    "9a7e1e7e-85d0-435e-8794-882679db10ce" [label="4014"]
    "e853d0ac-9b8a-4e74-a6c8-1ccad3044c33" [label="4013"]
    "2519b2bb-457b-4999-8789-7329cfa0f5a7" [label="4012"]
    "442913d6-7af5-42d2-8dd1-63dad14efb09" [label="4011"]
    "a35844d3-a419-4184-afe7-d12ab058b8db" [label="4010"]
    "8e842d52-141d-481f-a5ab-3baff04a1cf9" [label="4009"]
    "55b8b591-40e6-4aed-aae9-3a9489cd806f" [label="4008"]
    "dfc9cfc1-f190-4fd1-bd17-780413863a17" [label="4007"]
    "98c3d5b1-faf0-462c-b9f5-0ae3d530e694" [label="4006"]
    "2eb027f5-ec2e-4cf2-9faa-ecb1d36875a6" [label="4005"]
    "0eafc340-6753-410f-99c4-9058ee1c2451" [label="4004"]
    "c01fac09-cd8f-4903-afd1-671f7581f589" [label="4003"]
    "f7d6e56a-b6b8-4381-81d6-b06d1a30aa2b" [label="4002"]
    "fe7ae8b7-79b8-4605-a08b-a7e2af8a7e14" [label="4001"]
    "a4658afb-e92f-4f26-9b85-1ffa087a90f8" [label="4000"]
    "1f3dd47c-751d-4154-bb16-cd2d75215ff8" [label="3997"]
    "0114080b-d713-4023-b239-7c7dd4187f6b" [label="3996"]
    "909c894b-fc1c-4af5-905c-9fc3c9eba137" [label="3995"]
    "a3ca5be2-570d-4289-a683-0e10b06b1663" [label="3994"]
    "ee1e04bc-6c9e-4a0b-93eb-f612260a84f5" [label="3993"]
    "fe620d00-5806-48cf-b401-e43d93450c15" [label="3908"]
    "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391" [label="3907"]
    "974cc56a-7189-48b0-92b4-d22b950e074e" [label="3906"]
    "b9d93d71-7688-4fba-b3cb-342f5d1e0b1b" [label="3905"]
    "0e301fec-33cc-4904-aa3f-f67b8bc86f5a" [label="3904"]
    "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9" [label="3903"]
    "bb4e6be1-b9e8-4201-871d-d1b5ad5802f6" [label="3902"]
    "db88c2ca-620e-4ffd-9dd5-d511325cea30" [label="3897"]
    "c6bf6f2d-676e-42ab-a278-767a15e5e920" [label="3896"]
    "eaaa2ba7-7e2f-4b1f-9202-20d35584fa9b" [label="3895"]
    "08579851-d03e-4b2b-a181-a20b440c9489" [label="3894"]
    "1605342b-bacf-41fb-b58e-fd599bc6153c" [label="3891"]
    "f861bf3a-4068-4d1d-b265-a2313cd8ca17" [label="3890"]
    "112c245b-b5c8-4fae-98ae-1766c0cb5928" [label="3265"]
    "90eee544-ec97-4875-95a1-23949bd8c478" [label="2750"]
    "c4bffbf7-d258-4b5c-b87b-6a8bc861295d" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "8f86a5cc-8a0a-4380-91f5-2ab754ab9711" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "d77e4d0f-673c-4ac4-8411-ab7cc8ee840a" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "8e4d4f32-2689-4e3e-991b-95319d84ef8a" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "19998f18-4e0d-4060-8a3f-c66a6bb9ac22" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "e3ccf1ec-5aa6-4cd5-a66f-1c0b629093e5" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "8f7ac128-a046-43e7-ab51-c1214734a0c0" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "f7579872-4a5c-4594-937f-b264542d6637" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "38d04ed2-ea78-4c35-8265-76a58d71e3b5" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "e6ffca19-6b61-426e-8f8e-f8df40ccf4cd" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "bd120709-a05b-4e9c-a23e-67b656579327" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "820c6728-30c5-4d9f-bbe0-f772fa2d4b2e" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b" -> "4d990f29-cd09-44ab-8ff2-87f9a0bebe86"
    "5c08b7d4-faa0-45d1-8dad-e9bd2c7ef051" -> "3a54534d-b229-4db5-89be-f6402aaf5a9b"
    "b864bd1b-60ca-46a6-a1da-1ea189fef441" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "45c73173-a40e-4cbe-b673-a6ae80f2df9f" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "432c7e91-997a-46d8-a8f8-3298a7f7df58" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "4b450007-ad7a-4d7b-9df3-c082b80b00ca" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "13d9629e-f56f-4b47-bc99-376ecb14b076" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "c837a0a7-78d1-40ac-bf43-7868f0ff3957" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "a8cbc679-d6e8-4c6c-b715-cf8d7d23c555" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "40659aaf-fe64-42fc-ae94-9987ffb3b686" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "0de017a7-4ef4-495d-bee0-efaba0b4da02" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "6d517284-8254-4f10-ab98-2dea61c8d04f" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e" -> "4356074e-b446-474a-89e7-e93cc158d24e"
    "fa4565ee-59d5-4af2-b9bd-c1632d2a6c6c" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "2ce72a20-14b8-41f1-b21f-47a7681c6276" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "93a23f0d-c8b4-4a95-9f62-4502e42d87fc" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "a44919e5-8860-4e67-8c53-42e5d439c58e" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "2f4a908a-8269-4247-b374-729eac540269" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "db25cc7b-ab41-4389-a8dd-cb294b504fdd" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "7dd1a130-6c0f-475a-b432-562a0e338839" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "85d507d8-0c2f-413d-a0db-ceeaf5569adb" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "bbbc9a61-e2b2-4f6e-91cd-d46ae14b71fc" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809" -> "f2b95876-df48-49e4-8f88-9e32674c33a0"
    "1ac8fea0-791e-4d5b-9db5-095d1c1fee82" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "3846ee3e-36d1-495c-9adc-088c715c257d" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "c7b64c7b-c451-4d5b-905c-e465201905ef" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "c0b71383-6ab0-4786-90d7-4d50588df620" -> "7dd1a130-6c0f-475a-b432-562a0e338839"
    "9bc5c5f2-e45f-4ae8-817e-2e2a84d63d6e" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "ec25527a-f1cb-4827-896f-229fb135af50" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "30e0cc04-69bf-4a98-b5b7-ad102851a539" -> "c0b71383-6ab0-4786-90d7-4d50588df620"
    "fb573682-cf5f-4867-a40c-d151cb2dd5fd" -> "5c08b7d4-faa0-45d1-8dad-e9bd2c7ef051"
    "20fc5d12-f614-49e8-9836-9890bb3f7a37" -> "fb573682-cf5f-4867-a40c-d151cb2dd5fd"
    "5f0c0a21-cc3c-47d3-a143-a540b8f2681a" -> "83071b03-286a-4dd5-8f95-ccac1694d809"
    "a95a4daf-8b24-4e30-9a44-85b800e75bff" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "a20078e8-1df2-42a3-8f8c-bc5b821dd2a5" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "2c0c4fc1-3b3e-4a4e-aa7e-9f39c0302031" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "5224aa2b-5969-4433-97cb-0cfa0c5a5110" -> "c4727989-fc6e-4212-aa63-2efdd7f1d51e"
    "72233b5c-bf90-479f-9ede-8b8a6e921130" -> "c7b64c7b-c451-4d5b-905c-e465201905ef"
    "c9a96a2f-b6b7-4235-a131-b76489d6e230" -> "72233b5c-bf90-479f-9ede-8b8a6e921130"
    "2abf0a74-85ab-49eb-85bd-8429ec4d3bca" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "b5e4c5e3-bcc1-4620-9739-9a0a10915ac2" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "02b3d381-cf40-42ff-8a4e-67afaa049e2d" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "d58124c5-534d-4789-b6c3-8148f970b03f" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "5586a6e8-568c-466c-a3d0-88994b493b37" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "3e7781f4-5a64-4c49-be15-659669f51052" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "a1d06b37-6248-4756-80be-5cce023254a8" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "85b6d1ed-0458-46bc-8130-7f30a2fe6038" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "26f13b51-483f-4053-b2a0-a89e6c7dc181" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "22b6e967-70a7-4995-bee8-fa56babac7ac" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "76aa7f44-cdb8-4641-bcf0-627fdea8b8f8" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235" -> "25dfee0c-8686-4150-8f8e-ddb766f8fa11"
    "47e0d907-34d2-4257-ad81-9faf89fe3e59" -> "32889ff2-3761-4885-a088-fd9c9d82f235"
    "5ba6cd5e-0138-49f3-a874-52b09263d57c" -> "47e0d907-34d2-4257-ad81-9faf89fe3e59"
    "3dd16fdb-79c1-47e4-94e1-db4bf3e69e72" -> "5ba6cd5e-0138-49f3-a874-52b09263d57c"
    "3322a081-0b4f-4241-992a-044614ab260c" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "916d3373-19c5-4159-9115-7982c218dfb6" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "ee98f049-2a1f-468c-8f16-be9ca7d21d87" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "d85211ca-bd8e-4203-a046-644835033e54" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "b3ea090c-c534-4efa-802b-758f61c48fdb" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "b9694ce4-04b0-4964-a65d-ead392830ad4" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "d4b29e8e-a781-41f5-9e71-11029e12b157" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "0e80a296-e282-415c-a136-adb4ab285259" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "50ff3b85-f711-4eba-af67-7e4dfb8467bd" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "e60af8ef-0416-46b1-8a28-16fdf8b10a35" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "b4c59220-b3c4-471d-8fca-38daaffbd8b7" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "9291e7df-b044-4615-b816-1f964ce4f574" -> "7f64a959-37ba-4fe0-9990-968fd34e076b"
    "474ef404-ed96-4226-a080-6496a600fbdc" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "fe11be3f-fef2-4760-ad99-8e323f01748d" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "4cccf502-fe34-4c68-94fb-dfa25fc34b90" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "611d41f6-6540-4dec-95b6-fb21dc4e14a1" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77" -> "d21e0d43-7595-41dd-bdc9-3984b1e2e0ef"
    "0e8b0fcd-5fec-4aac-b65c-6e391bf7bfd1" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "dd0340d5-c0d5-40a6-a988-d7204ec6e783" -> "9291e7df-b044-4615-b816-1f964ce4f574"
    "940955cf-7bb8-497d-aea2-6e5d841b7fb1" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "f8bd4edb-8a09-4912-8edb-f14f368ef7c2" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "2322f347-7153-437a-843a-8f10a4e57e1b" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "10876c73-aef9-40ff-b5dd-259a4ce47292" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "ebb6349e-5432-4d0d-9101-e3d19d584a2c" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "216eaafa-5d84-4744-989e-7d9558314dca" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "9eeca7f7-ab14-4e38-8d64-8b9d54dff3f6" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "aecd60a1-436a-42c3-bdc8-227547e48ba5" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "77cad941-30ac-4b81-ad4a-4409f1da21ed" -> "dd0340d5-c0d5-40a6-a988-d7204ec6e783"
    "6e4639ef-8e6f-427f-a417-c344d736c27b" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "390ae27c-34de-49dd-b162-7bf898f3a44d" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "f93323bd-dc69-4f83-b920-0aad440339d5" -> "f861bf3a-4068-4d1d-b265-a2313cd8ca17"
    "864aa807-e56c-4aa2-93d6-1612710f2028" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "c8287fa1-e950-402e-aa8f-83995f3d44b6" -> "0da13c61-7759-4b48-951a-bcea048fad77"
    "825d4f6c-15dc-4be1-9318-a802d3f6bf12" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "eff5b030-606c-4dfa-8bb0-8fe92cd525df" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "f9d9e5b1-07da-44d4-934d-e88f53fc40f7" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "70e957b9-8f41-4b52-9480-ce3af6a3009b" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "09f4d03b-a1b3-4ed4-95c4-c62d9690982f" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "de83aa71-3a24-4d7a-8ca2-661a5d942c43" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "723ec621-ff8c-40ca-8efc-021dee4c4ef9" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "4a0ef549-0236-4a38-b32c-4769d25e5646" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057" -> "daf8022f-ae83-4336-98aa-0ace0a033243"
    "0a8b61ad-a068-4f75-8993-227149af0a57" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "c771b13f-cb34-42af-b8cd-44bcd600c777" -> "fee9052b-7c71-4323-9fba-adeb2f32fdcf"
    "adc7c5fc-e529-4141-a3f6-7a660f80a69f" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "cd9807ad-38bf-4738-9807-0854d5bdc3d9" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "fee9052b-7c71-4323-9fba-adeb2f32fdcf" -> "0a8b61ad-a068-4f75-8993-227149af0a57"
    "bda49732-7b5e-45ee-a38b-d6a0cb39fdde" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "b2a5fab8-c92d-4b88-9283-b8432841aa87" -> "2e28a740-7991-4cfe-8ed0-9d95c8181e29"
    "9983c8a8-6ef4-47e6-ae00-9f43dcdf5eeb" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "81190b5c-ab3a-41e8-935c-ac035710f90e" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "2e28a740-7991-4cfe-8ed0-9d95c8181e29" -> "bb4e6be1-b9e8-4201-871d-d1b5ad5802f6"
    "8912e27a-6c17-46ca-b01b-219711dd1505" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "b7bd2585-368e-4aa6-a512-c6a358f86af1" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "9a7e1e7e-85d0-435e-8794-882679db10ce" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "2519b2bb-457b-4999-8789-7329cfa0f5a7" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "442913d6-7af5-42d2-8dd1-63dad14efb09" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "a35844d3-a419-4184-afe7-d12ab058b8db" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "8e842d52-141d-481f-a5ab-3baff04a1cf9" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "55b8b591-40e6-4aed-aae9-3a9489cd806f" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "dfc9cfc1-f190-4fd1-bd17-780413863a17" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "98c3d5b1-faf0-462c-b9f5-0ae3d530e694" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "2eb027f5-ec2e-4cf2-9faa-ecb1d36875a6" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "0eafc340-6753-410f-99c4-9058ee1c2451" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "c01fac09-cd8f-4903-afd1-671f7581f589" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "f7d6e56a-b6b8-4381-81d6-b06d1a30aa2b" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "fe7ae8b7-79b8-4605-a08b-a7e2af8a7e14" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "a4658afb-e92f-4f26-9b85-1ffa087a90f8" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "1f3dd47c-751d-4154-bb16-cd2d75215ff8" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "909c894b-fc1c-4af5-905c-9fc3c9eba137" -> "1605342b-bacf-41fb-b58e-fd599bc6153c"
    "a3ca5be2-570d-4289-a683-0e10b06b1663" -> "909c894b-fc1c-4af5-905c-9fc3c9eba137"
    "ee1e04bc-6c9e-4a0b-93eb-f612260a84f5" -> "a3ca5be2-570d-4289-a683-0e10b06b1663"
    "974cc56a-7189-48b0-92b4-d22b950e074e" -> "ee1e04bc-6c9e-4a0b-93eb-f612260a84f5"
    "b9d93d71-7688-4fba-b3cb-342f5d1e0b1b" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "0e301fec-33cc-4904-aa3f-f67b8bc86f5a" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9" -> "e853d0ac-9b8a-4e74-a6c8-1ccad3044c33"
    "bb4e6be1-b9e8-4201-871d-d1b5ad5802f6" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
    "db88c2ca-620e-4ffd-9dd5-d511325cea30" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "eaaa2ba7-7e2f-4b1f-9202-20d35584fa9b" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "1605342b-bacf-41fb-b58e-fd599bc6153c" -> "067aec3d-e85b-4358-98da-9e489a74e5c9"
    "f861bf3a-4068-4d1d-b265-a2313cd8ca17" -> "c8287fa1-e950-402e-aa8f-83995f3d44b6"
    "112c245b-b5c8-4fae-98ae-1766c0cb5928" -> "31c30892-de23-41ae-a580-ea4dba7ee057"
    "90eee544-ec97-4875-95a1-23949bd8c478" -> "33f9237c-9252-497d-bf4c-817f3c857391"
}
```

I'm just given a completely black ~3200x300px image with a size of around 90kb. I can't figure out why this is the case. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a problem with your version/install.

Graphviz 2.28 on a windows system produces this output (11605x635px !):

[image: graphviz output]

Try `dot -version` to see version number and information about installed plugins & config file.

Comment: Yeah that's what it was, I updated and my problems are fixed now.Thanks!